# How can I decode chinese

Tags: java, decode, encode

I am just about to start decode something that I am sure is chinese and it looks like this in the database: `&#34913;`

The Sybase encodes is windows-1252 by default, but what is the above? How can I decode it to get the chinese chars written out. It is stored as nchar unfortunally.

In case anyone wonder
This is how its done:

```
int i = new Integer("34913").intValue();

String s = new String(Character.toChars(i));
```

As @Joachim said, thank you.

Comment: I would use `UTF-8` to ensure all characters can be encoded/decoded. I couldn't tell you if all Chinese characters can be safely encoded with windows-1252.

Comment: @Peter: windows-1252 can *not* represent all Chinese characters (in fact it can't represent any of them), as it's a ISO-8859-* derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a decimal numeric character reference](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes) [as defined by XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#dt-charref) (as well as [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3) and [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#character-references)). The number is the decimal representation of the Unicode codepoint.

Simply parse the number and cast it to an `int` to get the actual unicode codepoint. Then use [`Character.toChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars%28int%29) to get the corresponding `char` values (usually just one, but for characters outside [the BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) there will be two surrogate values).

Comment: Thanks @Joachim! I will try this and post my progress later on.